# Set correct input/output Devexpress gridcontrol cell mask

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have `gridcontrol` table and table in database.

I am able to display money data from database in `gridcontrol` (Display Format; "n0", custom)

I need to input special symbol `"<"` for which I want to create mask with RegEx value

`"(\\<)? \\d+(\\.\\d\\d)?"` (or something like this).

The issue is when I input `"<1"` it must displayed cell, but it **except error** (because display format is `"n0"`).

My requirement is to see table with numeric values, but when I input `"<1"` to this cell, it must display `"<1"`

**Summarizing: allow only numeric symbol and "<" sumbol to input and to display at cell**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in this way,

By using Properties Window, set `EditMask = (\<)\\?+[0-9]*` and set `MaskType = RegEx`

[image]

Comment: Yes, I made it already. Input works - allows symbol < and numbers. when I unfocus from this cell it calls error, wrong type

Comment: Did you set MaskType = RegEx?